# Newtons Heàdache

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image: conrains question figure]

Here 10 kg must experience a staic friction of maximum value 10N and hence shoud not move when 2N force is applied

But when another perspective is taken and both objects are considered a system then we observe a acceleration of 2/15 magnitude

What am i doing wrong?how?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This looks like a nice conceptual question but it's not unlikely to get closed for looking too much like a 'do my homework' type question. You can read the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) here.

Comment: To seem less off-topic it might help to add: more explanation of each of the two perspectives on the problem and why you think each is reasonable.

Comment: Why do you think the 10 kg block should not move? It's the  5kg block that will not slide on the 10 kg block. But both will move.

Comment: *[The] 10 kg must experience a static friction of maximum value 10N* This sentence makes no sense if the surface is smooth, as the drawing indicates. You can't have friction on a perfectly smooth surface.

Answer (score 4):

Friction is present between 5 kg and 10 kg. There is no relative motion between the two blocks since static friction is able to prevent it.

But there is no friction between 10kg block and floor. Hence the entire system accelerates with magnitude $\frac{2}{15} m/s^2$.